# Magento 2 Get Product Price excluding tax in phtml

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I've custom block phtml and I'm loading Product in it.

So how can I get Product price with including tax as well as excluding tax...

Rightnow I'm displaying price as

```
<?php echo $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue(); ?>
```

And for special price

```
<?php echo $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getAmount()->getValue(); ?>
```

But I want to display price with excluding tax and including tax, In backend it's setting is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Get your prices as folllows,

```
$priceWithoutTax = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount();
$priceWithTax = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount();
```

Comment: I got price as object with it.
Can you please let me know how to convert it in formatted price.?

Comment: echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($priceWithTax,2),true,false);;

Answer (score 1):

```
    $productPriceIncTax = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
    $productPriceExcTax = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue('tax');
```

For me This worked ^